# stancl/tenancy: How to fetch data from tenant db globally?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I used to fetch data from db and make available in all View through ServiceProvider, But now, I am using stancl/tenancy for multi-tenant system. And I need to pass some global data to all view files, writing the fetch data in ServiceProvider returns data from central database only. So, how can I fetch data from tenant DB to all view files globally before requesting any other requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Providers run *before* the tenant is identified and can therefore not be used to make configurations like sharing data to all views.

Instead, you can make a custom tenancy bootstrapper by creating a class that implements the `Stancl\Tenancy\Contracts\TenancyBootstrapper` interface.

```php
namespace App;

use View;
use Stancl\Tenancy\Contracts\Tenant;
use Stancl\Tenancy\Contracts\TenancyBootstrapper;

class ViewBootstrapper implements TenancyBootstrapper
{
    public function bootstrap(Tenant $tenant)
    {
        // Write your logic here.
        View::share('variable', 'data');
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        // Optional, but recommended:
        // Write you logic here that reverts the actions.
    }
}
```

Finally, add it to the `bootstrappers` array in your `config/tenancy.php` file to enable the bootstrapper.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, But you didn't get my question. I want to fetch data from tenant database, not the central database.

Comment: @amit I'm sorry, I just realised that too. I've updated my answers. :)